# How can I list directory contents in GnuCOBOL?

Tags: cobol, file-listing, gnucobol

I know my question is rather generic (and it looks like "please do all of my work for me"), so let me make it somewhat clearer: I'm - more or less - a COBOL beginner, the only thing I've done with it so far was a small FastCGI application for a single-serving page, just to *have done something* with it.

Now I'm considering to write a small file server in GnuCOBOL so I have *something real* to work with. I tend to learn new languages by writing stuff in them. While I *do* have an idea about how to read and process a specific file now, I still could need a clue about how I can collect and handle a specified directory's contents.

Sadly, the system calls [`C$LIST-DIRECTORY`](http://documentation.microfocus.com:8080/help/topic/com.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.extendACUSuite/BKPPPPLIBRS067.html?resultof=%22%43%24%4c%49%53%54%22%20),[`x"91"` function 69](http://documentation.microfocus.com:8080/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.visualcobol.vs2015%2FHRCLRHCALL6P.html), [`CBL_DIR_SCAN_START`](http://documentation.microfocus.com:8080/help/topic/com.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.visualcobol.eclipsewin/HRCLRHCALL7G.html?cp=5_6_3_11_11_10) and its sibling methods are still on the [GnuCOBOL Wish List](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/feature-requests/105/), so I can't just adapt existing solutions from the commercial COBOLs. I'm somewhat lost here.

Comment: Perhaps a better place to raise this is on the GnuCOBOL Discussion pages at SourceForge.Net. I'm not sure a small file server is an ideal way to learn COBOL, although your first foray into COBOL sounds interesting (there is a Contributions area on the GnuCOBOL site, and you may want to consider presenting that to a wider audience there). Anyway, it would be easier to discuss such things at the GnuCOBOL site.

Comment: Using languages for what they were made for is not an interesting task ... ;-)

OK, I'll see if I can find my SourceForge credentials again. I was just hoping the audience here would be larger. Thank you, though!

Comment: Fair enough. I don't want to discourage you :-)

Comment: What operating system?  GnuCOBOL is, in some ways, a lot like C.  `CALL` the system services that you have available.  Or, include something like cobweb-pipes and open a reader to `ls` with user defined functions.  `move pipe-open("ls", "r") to pipe-record ... perform until done ... move pipe-read(pipe-record, line-buffer) to pipe-transient ... move pipe-close(pipe-record) to pipe-status`

Comment: I develop the software mostly on Windows but I plan to use it mainly on BSD later. Well, I planned to - but I can guess from your answer that platform-independent solutions are not easily possible here? :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
call "system" using "dir /b > fileslist.txt" end-call
```

And then read in the listing file ...